# Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0

Tags: android, kotlin

Can you explain the solution to this please?

Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Comment: could you share your build gradle?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I resolved it by adding jitpack.io repository to build.gradle as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
       // jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
      //  jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}

    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I had previously included jcenter() to get this working but when I read that jcenter() is closing down soon I went looking for another solution.  Adding jitpack has solved it.

Answer (score 0):

**Please add philjay dependency in your app level build.gradle as below:**

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
```

**And add these lines inside dependencyResolutionManagement to your Settings.gradle:**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
```